# change encoding for param vectorLayerPath in qgis addVectorLayer()

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to add some shapefiles from my simple plugin using

```
selFile = "c:\åäö\myfile.shp"
fullName = selFile.replace('\\', '/').encode('utf-8')
layerName = "test"
Layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer(fullName, layerName, "ogr")
```

but that's not working due to the special characters åäö. (I have try to move some files to another folder and that's working)
When i load the files through "Menu->Layer->Add Layer->Add Vector Layer" it's working just fine

How to load them with python? I don't wont to move all my *.shp files.

Comment: try this: fullName = u"c:\åäö\myfile.shp"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and errors, the solution was easy.

```
addVectorLayer(uri, layername, 'delimitedtext')
```

this require an endoced 'utf-8' string for uri, but

```
addVectorLayer(uri, layername, 'ogr')
```

don't like the encoded string.

so my code now looks like this:

```
if selFile.endswith('.txt'):
    fullname = fullname.replace('\\', '/').encode('utf-8')
    layerName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fullname))[0]
    uri = 'file:///%s?crs=%s&delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s&decimal=%s&useHeader=%s' % (fullname, 'EPSG:3006', ',', 'East', 'North', '.', 'yes')
    layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer(uri, layerName, 'delimitedtext')

if selFile.endswith('.shp'):
    fullname = selFile.replace('\\', '/')
    layerName = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(fullname))[0]
    layer = self.iface.addVectorLayer(fullname, layerName, 'ogr')
```

And this works the way it should. Now i can import the files I want with just one button.